# How to update Puppy Linux?

Tags: linux, package-management, upgrade

A month or two ago, I installed the latest version of Puppy Linux to an old Eee PC which I hardly use any more. Well I'm on it now! But I can't figure out how to update it.

It uses a weird Puppy package manager which only seems to have options for installing and uninstalling things. I found an option to update the database, but that didn't actually update any of the software on my system.

I've looked through the menus several times and don't see anything that says update.

How do I update Puppy Linux??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please go through this blog as i think it exactly describes what you need : [how-to-update/upgrade-kernel-for-puppy-linux](http://pateo.wordpress.com/2009/12/25/how-to-updateupgrade-kernel-for-puppy-linux-dpup/)
I think this site could also help you.. [flash-puppy](http://www.puppylinux.com/flash-puppy.htm)
Another link which might help you is : [Update from 4.1.2 to 4.2](http://www.murga-linux.com/puppy/viewtopic.php?p=289827#289827)

Note : Take a look at this site also : [installing-puppy-linux-to-your-hard-drive](http://www.arsgeek.com/2006/12/05/installing-puppy-linux-to-your-hard-drive/)

Thanks,
Sen

Answer (score 0):

Hey the solution is very simple...
Just Go to `Menu > Setup > Puppy Updates`

It will update the system as we used to do in other linux distributions using `apt-get update`